# Prove ${y_n}$ is a basis for a Hilbert space $H$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ be orthonormal subsets of a Hilbert space $H$. If $\{x_n\}$ is a basis for $H$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|x_n-y_n\|^2<1$, prove $\{y_n\}$ is a basis for a Hilbert space $H$.

For any $z$ in $H$ , suppose $\langle z,y_k\rangle=0$ for all $k$, I want to show $z$ must be the zero vector. Write $z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle z,x_n\rangle x_n$, then we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\langle z,x_n\rangle \langle x_n,y_k\rangle=0$. But I have no idea how to deduce that $\langle z,x_n\rangle=0$ for $n$ so that $z=0$ since $\{x_n\}$ is a basis.

Comment: This is a variant of what is called the "Principle of small perturbations" and it works in general in Banach spaces. If $(x_n)$ is a normalized basis with basis constant $K$ and $(y_n)$ is a sequence such that $\sum||x_n-y_n||<\frac{1}{2K}$, then $(y_n)$ is a basis equivalent to $(x_n)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $z \neq 0$ and $\langle z,y_n\rangle=0$ for all $n$  then $\|z\|^2= \sum_{n} | \langle z,x_n\rangle |^2= \sum_{n}| \langle z,x_n-y_n\rangle |^2  \leq  \|z\|^2  \sum_{n} \| x_n - y_n\|^2  < \|z\|^2$. A contradiction.

Comment: nice proof! I did not thought of this.

Comment: Very elegant, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $x_{i}$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$, then $\langle x_{i}-x_{j},x_{i}-x_{j}\rangle=2$, so $|x_{i}-x_{j}|=\sqrt{2}$. The condition given implies for small $y_{i}$, $y_{i}\in B_{x_{i}}^{1}$. For large enough $i$ we have $|x_{i}-y_{i}|\rightarrow 0$ so they are approaching each other.

By condition given $H$ is separable. So it suffice to show each $x_{i}$ can be generated by the system $\{y_{i}\}$. Suppose otherwise, then the space $Y$ generated by $\{y_{i}\}$ is closed and convex. Therefore $|x_{i}-y|,y\in Y$ must have a minimal value because $Y-x_{i}$ is also closed and convex. Let the minimal value be $s$ such that $s>\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n$. Then we have $$\sum_{j=1}^{2n^{2}} |x_{i}-y_{j}|^{2}\ge \frac{1}{n^{2}}*2n^{2}=2$$which clearly contradicts.